# Formulae to convert WGS84 coordinates (B,L) to spherical coordinates (phi,lambda)?

Tags: coordinate-system, wgs84

How to convert WGS84 coordinates(B,L) to spherical coordinates(phi,lambda)?

I Need Formulae?

the thing I'm wondering seems quite simple but I've been searching through internet and library of my school about 3 days. I've found nothing about this. Maybe someone have done this before?

Comment: Welcome to GIS StackExchange! What are you asking for exactly? The formula to the conversion? You might want to include that in your question.

Comment: Please do state it in the question. People usually ask for software packages or good so it pays to make the question explicit.

Comment: Are you asking how to convert *ellipsoidal* coordinates (on the WGS84 ellipsoid) into *spherical* coordinates on a related sphere (of which there are many)?  What does "(B,L)" mean?

Comment: Yes I'm asking how to convert Ellipsoidal to Spherical. I'm using B,L because if I say lat,long or phi , lambda people may get confused which one is sphere or which one is ellipsoid. (B,L)------->Ellipsoidal latitude longitude

Comment: Please i need formulas and procedures to enable me convert wgs84 ellipsoid coordinates to Ghana War Office ellipsoid coordinates. I think it involves rotations,shifts and scaling but i don't know how to do that. Please help.

Comment: You can use http://epsg.io to find formulas and prodecures to transform coordinates between coordinate systems. But _Ghana_ _War_ _Office_ ellipsoid coordinates doesn't sound like a recognized coordinate system.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/142811)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll use spherical coordinates as defined here on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#mediaviewer/File:3D_Spherical_2.svg) which uses phi and theta (which is probably your lambda).

Phi is the angle from the north pole. Hence if the WGS84 point is 10.0.0N, phi will be 80 degrees. For a point in the southern hemisphere, say 12.30.00S, phi will be 90 + 12.5 = 102.5 degrees.

Theta is just the longitude in degrees, if the x-axis is the line going to the longitude=0 meridian (Greenwich). It's positive and between 0 and 180 for the eastern hemisphere and negative for the western hemisphere. This should just be the numeric value of your WGS84 longitude, with a "-" if its West. You can add 360 to negative thetas to get a range of 0 to 360.

If you need any spherical coordinates (phi or theta) in radians instead of degrees, then multiply by pi/180.

Comment: If this is the correct answer, could OP (or someone) please edit the question so it fits?

Comment: Actually this answer is right but not the one I'm looking for. I've edited question.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe *Spacedman* have already gave the answer but I was actually looking for formulae . I have found [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6079.png) page which is Turkish so I'll give you only the part you can understand. It says with this formulization we can transform our Geographic(Ellipsoidal) coordinates to Cartesian Coordinates. ( "h" is ellipsoidal height)

Then I have found [this](http://tr.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%BCresel_koordinat_sistemi) page which is Turkish again (but I'm sure you can find English one) describes how to transform Cartesian Coordinates to Spherical Coordinates.

So shortly my approach to this problem is like ;

**İnput:** Ellipsoidal Geographic Coordinates and ellipsoidal height.(GPS data of each point).

**Process:**
Transform this coordinates to Cartesian Coordinates. Then transform Cartesian Coordinates to Spherical Coordinates

**Output:** Spherical Coordinates.

Please let me know if you think this is a wrong approach for this problem or you think this is right way..

Comment: WGS coordinates are not Cartesian: they are coordinates on an *ellipsoid*.

Comment: Okey thats way I'm transforming them to Cartesian coordinates. (B,L) to X,Y,Z .

Comment: That would be earth-centered spherical coordinates.  There are other spherical coordinate systems for the earth.  What is the purpose of your intended conversion?

Comment: I'm trying to make some calculations on earth with an android program. Just like many other web services I'm using pseude-mercator for visualization of my map. Pseudeo-mercator uses Auxilary Sphere(a=6378137m) so we can say that it is a sphere. But GPS coordinates are ellipsodial.When user input GPS coordinates I need to convert these coordinates properly to the spherical coordiates. Which is not very common. Thats why I need it ...

Comment: You should read the outstanding account at https://alastaira.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/the-google-maps-bing-maps-spherical-mercator-projection/. Note particularly the passage "... the underlying geographic coordinates are defined using WGS84 (as in 3857), but projected as if they were defined on a sphere (as in 3785)." This means **you don't have to make any conversion at all:** you just pretend (lat, lon) for WGS84 *mean* (lat, lon) for a sphere.

Comment: I understand you . You are right in your way of thinking. But as I've said that before I'm trying to write a program which can make precise calculations. If you just want to visualize a shape object or just want to add a regular point on map you don't care about how precise it is. But if you want to calculate an area you'll need to convert. I've did it by the way and now I can calculate a 45 km2 area with 33 m2 error. It is possible if you convert your gps coordinates to cartesian and then spherical coordinates.

Comment: If you need precise calculations of areas then you will either need to use an equal-area projection or else convert the latitude to an [authalic latitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latitude#Authalic_latitude). The conversion you describe will give incorrect values.

Comment: Of course I couldn't write everything it was just abstract of what I've done . I'm trying to finish this project when I finish I'll put it to source forge and you'll understand.

Comment: What you have done is quite clear. I'm just warning you that for the purpose of precise calculations of geometrical quantities like area and length, it will not serve.

Comment: okey but have checked it as I have said before. I'm not trying to find the area of real earth surface. I need DEM for that. All want is to find area of a generally rectangle shaped object on the earth and of course it is impossible to calculate real area but I think 33m2 error on 45 km2 is quite good . I mean this error can be underestimated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19112/discussion-between-bukowski-and-whuber).